# Putting some polynomials in terms of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: polynomials, special-functions

I came across some polynomials which take the form

$$F_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}x^{n-2k}.$$

I noticed that these look pretty similar to the series for the Legendre polynomials $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{2n-2k}{k}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-2k}$$
and a little bit like the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind 
$$U_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}(2x)^{n-2k}.$$
Is there some way I could work the polynomials $F_n(x)$ in terms of Legendre polynomials, or some other 'special' polynomials or functions? The main issue is the floor function making it slightly difficult for me to recognise it in terms of e.g. some hypergeometric function or other special polynomials.

Reference would also be a great answer in the case that these are some polynomials with their own name.

Comment: Interestingly, while graphing your polynomials vs. the two you compare them to, it often seems your polynomials give a "middle" behavior between the Legendre and Chebyshev polynomials. Not sure if that's at all meaningful here, but I didn't expect it. Mind sharing where these polynomials came up?

Comment: To be brief, they come up in an electrodynamical problem, but there wasn't really anything to suggest that the Legendre polynomials should come up at all and it was a bit of a surprise to see them be so similar. What do you mean by "middle behaviour"?

Comment: Not quite sure how to formally describe it, but a Chebyshev polynomials looks a lot like a shrunk and squeezed in Legendre polynomial, and your polynomials fit somewhere in between, looking very much like the other two. Again, I don't claim it's meaningful, it merely surprised me a little.